# 'Invalid calling object' occurring with FancyBox in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancy box call:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            width   : 560,
            height  : 600,
            fitToView : false,
            autoSize : false,
        });
    });
```

This works fine in Chrome and FF but in IE (10 and below) I get the message:

```
SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object
```

in the console.

Im not sure what this means or how to fix it. I have systematically disabled other plugins to see if they are interacting with this but they are all fine - the problem persists.

The page I am working on is here http://pixelframe.com.au/test-page.html if anyone wants to take a look.

Would anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: On this line: `autoSize : false,` remove the trailing `,`

Comment: Trailing commas should only be a problem in IE<=7.

Comment: ANother thing I noticed was, `fancybox` is normally given on a `div` than `a`. Not sure how it is handled on an `a` tag though

Comment: @karthikr : fancybox is normally used within an anchor and gets the content from the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its a proper answer, but I reset the IE completely and it works. Weird.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man : he is the author answering his own question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you place a trailing comma in the last option, IE is expecting an identifier, string or number therefore it triggers a js error that prevents fancybox from working.

Remove the trailing comma from the last API option :

```
$(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width   : 560,
        height  : 600,
        fitToView : false,
        autoSize : false, //<== remove this comma
    });
});
```

This **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLS5h/show/)** doesn't work in IE7 for instance

Comment: IE is not "pickier" in any way. Trailing commas in the literal object and array syntaxes became valid as of ES5, which has only been standardized much after IE7's release.

Comment: No problem. I still think this is not the issue though, as OP reports an error in IE10. That is, the problem is probably not in the question's code.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I answered based on `10 and below`, however it's possible that something else is affecting. The document is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://pixelframe.com.au/test-page.html) and it doesn't even recognizes the `<head>` opening tag

Comment: @JFK thanks - Ive removed the comma but the issue is still the same